# Android Chrome clipboard write text/html does not appear to work

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

According to: https://chromestatus.com/feature/5357049665814528 it appears that Android Chrome does support clipboard copy of text/html.  It references the following example url: https://hyper-silly-cross.glitch.me/ which does not appear to work on any Android devices I have tried.

Can other developers confirm if Android Chrome does support this functionality?  It is working fine on other browsers, but not the mobile chrome.

Here is the typescript for our method we are trying to use...  It appears to be failing silently and the promise is being resolved, it would be nice to at least have an exception thrown we could subscribe to.

```
  copyEmailHtml(emailText: string) {
    const blobInput = new Blob([emailText], { type: 'text/html' });
    const clipboardItemInput = new ClipboardItem({ 'text/html': blobInput } as any);

    navigator.clipboard.write([clipboardItemInput]).then(() => {
      notification.emailCopied = true;
      this.emailCopied.emit(notification);
    }, (error) => {
      this.showDialog('Error copying to clipboard.  Your browser is not supported');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am reproducing this issue.

Coincidentally, [Issue 1342058: navigator.clipboard.write does not copy rich text (text/html) to clipboard](https://crbug.com/1342058) was created at Chromium's bugtracker very recently.